# How can I batch geocode street addresses from a csv file in to R?

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, ggmap

Edit; answer below.

Batch geocoding can be done like this using ggmap, file names are mine.  Code was adapted from [David Smith's Revolutions Blog Post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/07/making-beautiful-maps-in-r-with-ggmap.html)

```
library(ggmap)
#Read in csv file
FDNYHouse = read.csv("Path to your csv file here.csv")
#Get column header names if you don't already have them
names(FDNYHouse)
#Create a file of just addresses that need to be geocoded
#You can require a state by replacing State below with New York if state was missing
#Everything inside paste() is a column header from the csv file 
FDNYAddresses = with(FDNYHouse, paste(FacilityAddress, Borough, State, sep = ","))
#Now we can geocode the addresses
FDNYLocations = geocode(FDNYAddresses)
#The FDNYLocations file will have a lon and lat column representing your geocoded data
#My next problem is getting the shape file projection to match my geocoded points
```

I have created a census tract map of NYC using ggplot2 and a shape file.  Next, I'd like to create a data frame using street addresses of fire houses to lay over the top of the map using a csv file I downloaded here:

[FDNY Firehouse Locations](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/FDNY-Firehouse-Listing/hc8x-tcnd)

The shape file for census tracts is locate here (it's the 2010 version in black):

[NYC Shape File](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwndistricts.shtml)

My problems are that the data doesn't list city and state, and that I don't know how to write a function that can grab these addresses and geocode them with Google ***using something like ggmap***.

Any advice or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.  I'm new to R and stackoverflow so go easy on me.

Edit:  Did anyone who marked this as already asked either A) look at my actual data or B) realize that the question you think I repeated is 3 years old? Guess nothing new has happened in R in the last 3 years right? The world is flat, move along folks. /rant

I can use ggmap and the geocode() function to get lat and lon without creating a function to do it.

```
#As an example
install.packages("ggmap")
library(ggmap)
geocode("San Francisco")
```

The problem, again, is how to tell R to read my csv file, which is missing city and state data, so that it can create the 200+ lat and lon measurement I need without me having to geocode 1 address at a time.

The second issue is then taking this data, making a data frame and adding it to the NYC shape file I already have.

That answer from 3 years ago is complicated and confusing for someone without the experience most people who looked at this post have...I also believe it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The firehouse location data contains a street address and borough.  The shapefile gives firehouse number, battalion and division.  I have seen questions asking how to assign data to a zip code, but never a question asking how to assign a street address to a polygon.  You might end up having to manually enter either the zipcode and/or lat-long coordinates for each firehouse to the street address file.  But that is a guess.  Maybe there is a way to assign a street address to a GIS layer.  Sorry I cannot give better advice.

Comment: From following the link RJ provided I found this website that perhaps can assign postal addresses to a GIS layer without Lat-Long coordinates: https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/Default.aspx

Comment: Following the link I posted, you can geocode the addresses using the `FDNY Firehouse Locations` data. While it doesn't list city or state, you can limit the location for more accurate geocoding. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index. Following that, you can then do a point in polygon test for the NYC shapefile.

Answer (score 2):

I recently solved a similar problem.  Below are two pieces of code.  The first function converts addresses to lat/lon (if you can't abide by Google's terms of use, look for the Data Science Toolkit as a good standalone alternative for `geo-coding`.)  The second function looks at a given lat/lon pair and determines which polygon (Census tract) contains those coordinates.  Very useful for doing `choropleth` maps.

```
library("RJSONIO") #Load Library
library("plyr")
library("RODBC")
library(maptools)

getGeoCode <- function(gcStr)
{ gcStr <- gsub(' ','%20',gcStr) #Encode URL Parameters
  #Open Connection
  connectStr <- paste('http://http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=',gcStr, sep="") 
  con <- url(connectStr)
  data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(con, warn = FALSE), collapse=""))
  close(con)
  #Flatten the received JSON
  data.json <- unlist(data.json)

  if (data.json["status"] == "OK" && data.json["results.geometry.location_type"] == "ROOFTOP") {
    address <- data.json["results.formatted_address"]
    lat <- data.json["results.geometry.location.lat"]
    lon <- data.json["results.geometry.location.lng"]
    gcodes <- data.frame("Address" = address, "Lon" = as.numeric(lon), "Lat" =     as.numeric(lat))
    return (gcodes)
  } else return ()
}

# Testing...
geoCodes <- getGeoCode("Palo Alto,California")
geoCodes
# "-122.1430195" "37.4418834" 



# Required for TractLookup
Washington <-readShapePoly("g:/USCensus/tl_2012_53_tract/tl_2012_53_tract")       
# US Census tract files (includes shape and data files)


tractLookup <- function(x) {
  # pt <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(x = -80.1, y = 26.3))
  pt <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(x = x$Lon, y = x$Lat))
  Mapping <- over(pt, Washington) # what index number does pt fall inside?
  Mapping <- data.frame(
  "GEOID" = as.character(Mapping$GEOID),
  "State" = as.character(Mapping$STATEFP) , 
  "County" = as.character(Mapping$COUNTYFP), 
  "Tract" = as.character(Mapping$TRACTCE), 
  "Tract_Name" = as.character(Mapping$NAME), 
  "INTPTLAT" = as.character(Mapping$INTPTLAT),
  "INTPTLON" = as.character(Mapping$INTPTLON),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  Mapping[is.na(Mapping)] <- "NULL"   
return(Mapping)
}

tractLookup(data.frame("Lon" = -122, "Lat" = 47.5))
# GEOID State County  Tract Tract_Name    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON
# 1 53033032102    53    033 032102     321.02 +47.4851507 -121.9657839
```

Looking at the New York fire department shape file, you should be able to change the mapping statement to look for and return the appropriate fields in place of the GEOID and tract information from the standard US Census shape file in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

```
# Geocoding a csv column of "addresses" in R


#load ggmap
library(ggmap)


# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)


# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))

{
# Print("Working...")
result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}


# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

[image]